# Gradient and Laplacian in $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, quantum-mechanics, laplacian

I'm trying to solve the [particle in a ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_ring) problem without embedding the circle in $\Bbb R^3$, by instead taking the entire space to be $S^1$.  Unfortunately, I haven't taken differential geometry yet and am unsure of how the gradient (or really the laplacian) is found in this space.  I assume it should still come out to being $\nabla^2 = \frac 1{r^2} \frac {\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}$, but I don't how to derive that.  Is this something simple enough that you guys could explain it in a post, or do I just need to study differential geometry before attempting to solve a problem like this?

---

Edit:

What I've got so far is $$\frac {\partial^2 \psi(x)}{\partial x^2}=\frac{-2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi(x)$$ where $\psi(x)=\psi(x+2\pi Rn),\ n \in \Bbb Z$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x)|^2 dx = 1$.
$$\implies \psi(x)=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}=Ae^{ik(x+2\pi Rn)}+Be^{-ik(x+2\pi Rn)}$$
$$\psi'(x)=ikAe^{ikx}-ikBe^{-ikx}=ikAe^{ik(x+2\pi Rn)}-ikBe^{-ik(x+2\pi Rn)}$$
$$\psi''(x)=-k^2Ae^{ikx}-k^2Be^{-ikx}=-k^2Ae^{ik(x+2\pi Rn)}-k^2Be^{-ik(x+2\pi Rn)}$$
$$\implies -k^2(Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx})=\frac{-2mE}{\hbar^2}(Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx})$$
$$\implies k=\sqrt{\frac {2mE}{\hbar^2}}$$

but I don't know how to find $A$ and $B$.

---

Edit 2:
@CameronWilliams, is the periodic boundary condition, $\psi(x)=\psi(x+2\pi Rn),\ n \in \Bbb Z$, not enough to specify $A$ and $B$ then?  Because I haven't really found a way to use that condition, yet.

Comment: You can't determine $A$ and $B$ without initial/boundary conditions. This is a common theme throughout differential equations..

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses the issue of the Laplacian on $S^1$ and not the issue of whether you are solving the differential equation correctly.

Circles are completely classified by their radius $r$, or if you prefer, by their circumference $C$, where of course $C = 2 \pi r$. What I mean by this is that whether or not your circle is originally given to you as being embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual way, you can always view it as being embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, in the sense that there is an isometry (a length-preserving bijective smooth map) between the original circle and the usual one in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For your purposes, I would guess that the distinction between the original circle and the one in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not too important.

This means that your circle can always be parametrized by the coordinate $\theta$, where $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$. If you are familiar with tangent vectors in an abstract setting, the tangent vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ has constant length $r$ (which, remember, is a fixed constant). You can also parametrize the circle with respect to arc length, say, using the coordinate $t$, where $0 \leq t < 2\pi r$, and the tangent vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ has constant length $1$.

The Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\Delta u = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_k^2}$. This formula relies on the fact that the coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are the usual Euclidean coordinates, or, in other words, that the tangent vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$ are *orthonormal*. On a more general Riemannian manifold, the key thing to remember is that the same formula for $\Delta$ applies, but *only* as long as one is working in a coordinate system that is *orthonormal* (to second order, meaning the first derivatives of the metric tensor vanish).  In a general coordinate system, the Laplacian is given by
$$ \Delta u = \sum_{j,k} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left( \sqrt{|g|}   g^{jk} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_k}  \right), $$
where $|g|$ is the determinant of the metric tensor $(g_{jk})$ and the $g^{jk}$'s are the components of the inverse of the metric tensor. If the coordinate system is orthonormal to second order at a point, then this formula (at that point) reduces to the familiar formula from $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Note it is not generally possible to choose such a coordinate system globally, or even in a small open set, but we can always choose one so that those properties hold at a single point at the center of the coordinate system.)

You can read more about the Laplacian on Riemannian manifolds on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator), for example. That article also contains links to articles about the gradient and divergence, including discussion of those operators on manifolds. I suppose this may not be too useful if you don't know any differential geometry, but you still might want to take a look.

Now, back to the circle: Recall the two coordinates $\theta$ and $t$ that we could use to parametrize the circle. Since the circle is one-dimensional, there is no sum on $j$ and $k$ in the formula for $\Delta$. If we use $t$ (an orthonormal coordinate system), $g_{tt} = g^{tt} = |g| = 1$, so we obtain simply $\Delta u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$. If we use $\theta$ (not orthonormal but still quite simple), $g_{\theta \theta} = |g|= r^2$ and $g^{\theta \theta} = \frac{1}{r^2}$ (remember, $r$ is a constant), so we obtain $\Delta u = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}$, as you claimed.

To summarize, you have to divide by $r^2$ in the $\theta$ formula for $\Delta$ to account for the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ has length $r$, and that you are taking two derivatives with respect to $\theta$. This correction is not necessary when you use the coordinate $t$, since $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ has length $1$.